# How to remove junk characters from the file generated by script command in linux

Tags: text-processing, escape-characters

I am using script command to record everything from terminal. But when I am opening the generated file its having lots of junk character.
Can anyone help me to remove these junk characters from file or any other alternate way?

This file look like this:

```
ossvm10(0)> ls -lrt /usr/opt/temip/mmexe/mcc_fcl_pm.exe^M
^[[00m-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 387517 Feb 18  2013 ^[[00;32m/usr/opt/temip/mmexe/mcc_fcl_pm.exe^[[00m^M
^[[m^[]0;temip@ossvm10:/home/dharmc^G[/home/dharmc]^M
ossvm10(0)> script -a unit_testing_TEMIPTFRLIN_00202_CR#9961.txtsum /usr/opt/temip/mmexe/mcc_fcl_pm.exe^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^[[1P^H^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^H^[[1P^[[1P^H^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^M
06046   379^M
^[]0;temip@ossvm10:/home/dharmc^G[/home/dharmc]^M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run:

`dos2unix <filename>`

This will remove all the `^M` characters from the file. ^M is the carriage-return character generated in a DOS environment. The command `dos2unix` just converts the file from DOS to Unix format.

To remove the `^H` and `^G` characters, use `sed`:

`sed -i 's/\^H//g;s/\^G//g' <filename>`

Comment: `dos2unix` will just clear out the ^Ms, it won't help with the ansi coding that got recorded.

Comment: Thanks sree, but this has just removed the ^M characters. What about ^H,^G and some other junk characters?

Comment: @Dharmendra, updated the answer. Please take that as an example to remove junk characters other than ^H and ^G.

Comment: ^H is backspace, won't removing them alter the semantics of the record? (i.e. `ha^Hi` is becomes `hai` when it should be `hi`)

Comment: Yes, @Sree but still that is not working for "^[[m^[]0;" or "[1P". Anyway Thanks.